# Lua: How to get string captures containing a specific substring?

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

In Lua, in want to get captures from a string containing a specific substring. E.g. in the string

```
 test = "<item>foo</item>  <item>bar</item>"
```

I want to get items containing "a", which in this case would be "bar". I tried this:

```
print(string.find(test, "<item>(.-a.-)</item>"))
```

but the result is:

```
1   34  foo</item>  <item>bar
```

So .- is more greedy than I expected. What would be the correct pattern?

Comment: Do not parse XML with patterns.

Comment: This wasn't meant for parsing, I'm looking for specific parts in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `print(string.find(test, "<item>([^<]-a.-)</item>"))`.